# Why is that gdsr_sort=thumbs (GD start rating plugin) only works with query_posts and not with WP_Query?

Tags: query-posts, plugin-gd-star-rating

This correctly sort posts by thumbs vote ([GD star rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/) plugin):

```
<?php query_posts('gdsr_sort=thumbs&post_type=bbp_reply&posts_per_page=2&post_parent='.$post->ID); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php  the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

But this doesn't sort them at all:

```
        <?php $custom_posts = new WP_Query(); ?>
        <?php $custom_posts->query('gdsr_sort=thumbs&post_type=bbp_reply&posts_per_page=2&post_parent='.$post->ID); ?>
        <?php while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="content-block-2">
                    <?php bbp_reply_author_link( array( 'type' => 'avatar' ) ); ?>
                    <?php bbp_reply_author_link( array( 'type' => 'name' ) ); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems [GD Star Rating uses `get_query_var()`](http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/gd-star-rating/tags/1.9.7/code/blg/query.php#L76) to read query variables, which only reads this global `$wp_query` variable. `query_posts()` overwrites the global `$wp_query` variable, so it works there, but creating a new `WP_Query` (which is a good practice) will not work. You should contact the plugin author and ask for a fix.

Comment: Still not fixed as of latest version 1.9.10. Thanks for the info, Jan.

Comment: I hardcoded the get parameters to always sort, maybe that helps somebody else:add_action("init", "MuviceInit",1);
function MuviceInit() { 
 global $muvice;
 $_GET["gdsr_sort"]='thumbs';
 $_GET["gdsr_order"]='desc';
 $muvice = new Muvice(); 
}

Answer (score 1):

Cilvic's advice works for me. Just set the GET parameters before using WP_Query.

```
$_GET['gdsr_sort'] = 'rating';
$_GET['gdsr_order'] = 'desc';
```